# Cakephp 2.5. Getting error when using bind / unbind

Tags: cakephp

I calling this in my controller:

```
public function index() {
        $this->Product->recursive = 2;
        $this->Product->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Productproperty')), true);
        $this->Product->Ranking->unbindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Product', 'Contacts')), true);

        $this->Product->Ranking->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Customer' => array('foreignKey' => false))), true);

        $this->set('products', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
```

I get all the date I want to, the statements are correct shown in debug. 
Data output is correct and perfect to me.

But I get this error message on the screen:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 1695]

I wonder why dboSource is involved?
Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: If you look at the line of code generating the error - it's probably `false`. Adding the sql log to the question would help. You're better off using containable from what's in the question. `bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Customer' => array('foreignKey' => false)` <- what's the purpose of removing the foreign key? If there's no conditions (?) that will result in nonsensical results.

Answer (score 0):

From [DBOSource line 1695](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L1695)

```
foreach ($conditions as $key => $condition) { ... }
```

it seems to me that your simply missing 'conditions' in your paginate query. Have you tried putting anything in there? Maybe after unbinding default structure changed and somehow was lost? It could be CakePHP bug I think.

Comment: Well, even if I add some conditions like
public $paginate = array('limit' => 25); the query will not change and the error message remains. And the calls from action index() are still the same, this is really everything I do in this function...

Comment: `It could be CakePHP bug I think.` - Highly unlikely. @user1555112 in the above comment you _aren't_ adding any conditions; you're just defining the limit.

Comment: Try defining 'conditions' => array(); or with just anything in the array for test. Well if paginate normally works without conditions and suddenlly after unbidingModel it not working without conditions set its seems like odd behaviour to me? I am just guessing, dont know if its something with his syntax or problem withig his models, maybe its like you mentioned in abouve comment about removing foreignKey. Lets see if he will try to apply any fix and what will help him out.

Answer (score 0):

After re-thinking the structure and many hours trial and error ... :-)
It was indeed a syntax mistake caused by myself.
This is my solution:

```
public function index() {
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Statistiken');
        $this->Product->recursive = 3;
        $this->Product->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Productproperty')), true);
        $this->Product->Ranking->unbindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Product', 'Contacts')), true);

        $this->Product->Ranking->Contact->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Ranking')), true);

        $this->set('products', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
```